# What does it mean when one cardinal number is less than another

Tags: set-theory

The cardinality of a set $A$, denoted $|A|$, is defined as the equivalence class of $A$ under the equivalence relation $A \sim B \Rightarrow f: A \to B$, where $f$ is a bijective map.

The class of all cardinal numbers can be ordered using Zorn's lemma. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all pairs $(f, X)$ such that $X \subseteq A$ and $f: X \to B$ is an injective map. If $X_1 \subseteq X_2$ and $f_2 \mid X_1 = f_1$, then $(f_1, X_1) \le (f_2, X_2)$. It can be shown that $\le$ defines an ordering on $(f, X)$. You can then show that each chain has a maximal element and apply Zorn's lemma and deduce that $\mathcal{T}$ is linearly ordered.

My question is: if we say $|A| \le |B|$, do we mean the above ordering on $(f, X)$, or do we mean any ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|A|\leq |B|$ is a relation that connects $A$ and $B$, whereas the ordering that you have defined on the set of all the $(f,X)$ is a relation on the set $\{(f,X)\mid X\subset A\land f : X\to B$ is injective$\}$.

Zorn's lemma here is only useful to prove what is called "the dichotomy of cardinals" (also known as "trichotomy", I don't know which is more common but for my purposes here, "dichotomy" makes more sense) which is : for any sets $A$ and $B$, either there is an injection $A\to B$, or there is an injection $B\to A$.

Now $|A|\leq |B|$ is the statement that there exists an injective map $f: A\to B$; so it's not "the above ordering on $(f,X)$".

Moreover, what you can deduce is certainly not that $\mathcal{F}$ is linearly ordered, what you can deduce is that $\mathcal{F}$ has a maximal element (and to do so, you need not show that each chain has a maximal element, you need only show that it is bounded above).

This maximal element, let's call it $(f,X)$ allows you to prove the dichotomy. Indeed there are two cases :

-either $X=A$, and thus there is an injective map $f: A\to B$,

-either $X$ is a proper subset of $A$,in which case, since $f$ cannot be extended to an injective map, it means that $f$ is surjective, and so $f$ is bijective, and $f^{-1}$ is an injection $B\to A$.

Answer (score 2):

We mean the very specific ordering that $|A| \leq |B|$ if and only if there is an injection $A \to B$. This is an ordering which is not captured by a set: the class of all cardinals is too big to be a set. So I think you're appealing to some kind of "industrial-strength" Zorn, because you're attempting to order a proper class: Zorn only provides orderings of sets.

Comment: Actually, you do not use Zorn's lemma directly on the class of all cardinal numbers. You use it on the set $\mathcal{T}$. This is what Hungerford uses in Algebra Theorem 8.7 in order to prove the trichotomy law.

Comment: @Patrick : OP is simply mistaken on what he/she is trying to prove.